# Asus N53SN nvidia optimus settings?

Tags: nvidia-optimus

i have asus N53SN which has 2 graphics card intel and geforce gt550M and used bumblebee. but i have a problem which i dont know when intel or geforce is going to work. is there any way for me to select intel or geforce when i want?

using ubuntu 13.04 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

By default with the bumblebee project, you need to tell what applications will use the Nvidia card for rendering with the `optirun` command:

```
optirun firefox
optirun awesome_game
optirun gimp
optirun mplayer
```

Check the [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Usage) for more information, or use `optirun --help`.